# Why do I need to rescue exceptions?

Tags: ruby, exception

Are there any other reasons to handle an exception with `rescue` except for not letting my program to crash and continue working?

Comment: I think _not having a program to crash_ is a huge advantage. I am not sure what kind of answer you expect? Something like: return a proper error message to the user, handle the error and do not fail, cleanup some things you did before the crash...? Something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody's forcing you to rescue exceptions. You can let it burn if you want, and in some situations this is a perfectly viable strategy. Sometimes it's better to crash than to muddle along and proceed as if nothing bad happened.

In systems where exceptions are logged and the process is automatically restarted this may be the way to go.

The last thing you want to do is jam in a `rescue` that does nothing other than obscure problems, or worse, leaves the system in an unstable or non-working state. This is the equivalent of disconnecting a fire alarm because it's annoying and beeps once in a while. One day you're going to need it because something serious is happening.

Most of the time exceptions communicate something useful, they're not a nuisance. Like this:

```
class ConfigDataError < StandardError
  # Defines a custom exception class
end

def config_data(path)
  YAML.load(File.open(path))
rescue Errno::ENOENT
  # File is missing, no big deal.
  { }
rescue Psych::SyntaxError
  # This is a problem!
  raise ConfigDataError, "Invalid YAML in file #{path}"
end
```

Where you can target certain kinds of *expected* exceptions as well as being able to re-raise other exceptions as a new type.